# Adding a custom object to a change set?

Tags: force.com, change-set

when you add a custom object to a change set, what does it include? Is it just the object and it's standard fields?

I couldn't find the documentation that said this specifically...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through a change set I believe that the target org creates only the custom object and not any custom field/ validations / anyrelated properties.

Simple check: Try deploying a test apex class referencing a test object's field and try to deploy the class, and object excluding the test field. Your deploy would fail prompting that the field does not exist related to the test object.

Comment: You are correct

Answer (score -2):

Why would you ever want to deploy a custom object without all of its fields?

Why is this not the standard behavior?

Tracking down sometimes a hundred or more fields is pretty tedious.